# How to repeat string without a function

Tags: python, string, function

I found a task where I am asked to implement some object that repeats a string n times but condition is that this something must not be a function. I have tried the following:

```
class str_repeat:
         def __init__(self,x,y):
                  self.s = x * y
         def __repr__(self):
                  return self.s
```

but this did not work.Some Hints would help a lot

Comment: what do you mean by "this did not work"? Your class works for me.

`print str_repeat("s", 4)` out: `ssss`

Comment: what exactly is meant by "must not be a function"?

Because `__init__()` is a function, and technically, so is the `*` operator. So unless that task gives some more information about what is and isn't allowed and just says "you can't use any functions", then it's impossible.

Although I assume that whoever wrote that task probably just wanted you to use the `*` operator.

Comment: output was strange -  **'aaaa' should equal 'aaaa'**.

Comment: I will give you link to that task if you want to see description yourself

Comment: In your case all work. You must only create object and pront `s` value. `my_string = str_repeat('string', 5)` and if you do this `print(my_string.s)` you see words `string` 5 times

Comment: @Shalva123 share the link to the task.

Comment: here - https://www.codewars.com/kata/string-repetition-without-function , point is that this **something** should be callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Humm! `str_repeat` must be a callable.

What do you think of:

```
str_repeat = str.__mul__
```

Comment: Hah,that did the trick, thank you, but I am little dissapointed as I wanted to do it myself I just wanted a hint. Anyway, Thanks a lot